# Is it possible to optimize these 2 select statements into one?

Tags: sql, database, web, multiple-select

```
Select 1 
from Friend 
where Friend.UserID = 1 
  and FriendID = (select User.UserID from User where UserName = 'friend_user');
```

What I'm trying to do is to check whether a user is "friends" with another user. So when the user navigates to "foo.com/user/username" the username is passed and that's when I do the check.  I would prefer to not use two selects but it seems that's the only way to do this. Any suggestions to the best way of doing a task like this would be appreciated.

Comment: You are **not** using two selects. You have a single select with a co-related subquery. With a modern DBMS (and a decent query optimizer) chances are very high that there is no difference in the efficiency of your statement and the accepted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `JOIN` instead:

```
Select 1 
from Friend f
join User u
    on f.FriendID = u.UserID
    and u.UserName = 'friend_user'
where 
    f.UserID = 1;
```

Comment: This works, but what if I wanted to select stuff from the User table, like the Friends UserName and such?

Comment: @user979663 This is easy when using `JOIN`.  Simply add the fields to your `SELECT` statement, and prefix them with the `u` table alias.

Comment: Ok its all starting to click now haha

Answer (score 1):

Answer to: "This works, but what if I wanted to select stuff from the User table, like the Friends UserName and such? –"

```
Select u.username, count(f.friends)
from Friend f
join User u
    on f.FriendID = u.UserID
    and u.UserName = 'friend_user'
where 
    f.UserID = 1;
```